# F-mount extension tubes suddenly stop attaching to Nikon d5100

Tags: nikon-d5100, extension-tubes

I just got a new Nikon d5100. I attached some extension tubes, took some pictures, took off the extensions tubes, took some more pictures. When I tried to re-attach the extension tubes they would not "lock" in, meaning they attach into the camera body hole, but will not twist all the way around so they click in place; so the camera doesn't sense the lens.

Lenses by themselves still attach to the d5100, and the extension tubes still attach to an f100, but magically none of the extension tubes in the extension tube set will now lock into the d5100, though they did previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the extension tubes have a little tab on the edge that was getting jammed against another tab on the rim of the f-mount (which is on a spring and supposed to get pushed down), preventing the extension tubes from being twisted around completely and locked into place.
[image]